# отправленный комментарий к фото не сохраняется в бд

Tags: python, django

1. `models.py`
2. ```
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')
   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save()
       img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
       if img.height > 900 or img.width > 900:
           new_img = (900, 900)
           img.thumbnail(new_img)
           img.save(self.avatar.path)
   class Avacomments(models.Model):
       to_user_com = models.ForeignKey(Profilava,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       ot_user_com = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       comment_content = models.TextField(null=True)
   ```
3. forms.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Avacomments
        fields = ('comment_content',)
        widgets = {
            'comment_content': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'коммент'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            profiles_form = ProfilavaForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profilava)
            form = GostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

            avacomment = CreatecommentavaForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            if profiles_form.is_valid and form.is_valid and avacomment.is_valid():
                # проверка на пустоту загрузки в галерею
                try:
                    if 'ima' in GostForm(request.POST,request.FILES['ima']):
                        pass
                    else:
                        user = form.save(commit=False)
                        user.users = request.user
                        user.save()
                except:
                    pass
                profiles_form.save()
                avacomment.save()   #<<<------
                # удаление коментариев  и лайков к аватарке
                try:
                    if 'avatar' in GostForm(request.POST,request.FILES['avatar']):
                        pass
                    else:
                        avali = Profilava.objects.get(user=request.user.pk)
                        Avacomments.objects.filter(to_user_com=avali).delete()
                        Avalike.objects.filter(to_user=avali).delete()
                except:
                    pass
                messages.success(request, 'Your profile is updated successfully')
                return redirect('mprofil')
            

        else:
            profile_form = ProfilavaForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profilava)
            avacomment_form = CreatecommentavaForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            form = GostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            posts = Gost.objects.filter(users=request.user.pk)
            kolimags = posts.count()
            avali = Profilava.objects.get(user=request.user.pk)
            avalis = Avalike.objects.filter(to_user=avali)
            avaliss = (avalis.count())
            list_comment = Avacomments.objects.filter(to_user_com=avali)
            return render(request, 'board/mprofil.html', {
                'profileava_form': profile_form,
                'form':form, 'posts': posts,
                'kolimags': kolimags, 'avaliss': avaliss,
                'list_comment':list_comment,
                'avacomment_form':avacomment_form,
                })       
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

4. html

````
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ avacomment_form.as_p }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">отправить</button>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            {% for comment in list_comment %}
                                <li class="list-group-item">от: {{ comment.ot_user_com.first_name }} {{ comment.ot_user_com.last_name }}<br>комментарий: {{ comment.comment_content }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>```
````

Comment: Вы разместили в вопросе обрывки модели, обрывки описания формы, обрывок класса представления. 

1) Это не удобно для восприятия. 
2) Ошибка может быть в том фрагменте который вы не опубликовали.

В программировании есть такой термин "отладочный print()". Метод заключается в том чтобы добавить в проблемный фрагмент кода строки print('ваша_переменная') которые выведут в консоль содержимое переменных. Таким образом вы сможете найти переменные которые должны содержать данные но почему то являются пустыми.